# Which countries regulate use of the term "vegan"?

Tags: veganism, is-it-vegan, travel, legislation

Which countries have laws that make it illegal to label a product as "vegan" if it contains parts from animals (or insects)?

Unfortunately, I've seen a lot of products marked "vegan" (or [plant-based](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/276/is-there-a-difference-between-vegan-and-plant-based?noredirect=1&lq=1)) for marketing purposes, but the ingredients contain dead animals' bodies (eg beef stock, leather) or things derived from living animals (eg milk, eggs, honey).

I'd like to find a list of countries that explicitly make it criminal to label something "vegan" when it's not in compliance with their laws that define the requirements for labeling something as "vegan."

Comment: In Apr 2016 the German government voted to create their first legally-binding definition of "vegan" and "vegetarian ("vegan" und "vegetarisch") https://proveg.com/de/was-wir-tun/politische-arbeit/lebensmittelkennzeichnung/veggie-definition/

Comment: See also https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/are-there-any-countries-besides-india-where-it-is-mandatory-to-mark-food-product

Comment: See also [Has any government banned animal slaughter for human consumption? Was it effective for increasing animal rights?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1267/has-any-government-banned-animal-slaughter-for-human-consumption-was-it-effecti?rq=1)

Comment: See also https://www.elephantjournal.com/2009/10/at-buddhists-request-taiwan-enacts-worlds-strictest-law-on-veggie-food-labeling/