# Are plants grown with animal manure vegan?

Tags: is-it-vegan

Many farmers use a method known as *manure* to plant vegetables. This manure comes from animals.

Generally vegans don’t benefit from products that come from animals.

So are vegetables that are grown with animal (as opposed to synthetic) manure considered vegan?

Comment: A good question, but I'm wondering what you mean by synthetic manure. My vegan parents use seaweed fertilizer for their garden.

Comment: I expect that this will be mainly opinion based.  If I collect animal dung from the wild, I am not harming the animals in any way.  However, in practice, the dung probably comes from farmed animals.  Howabout sourcing your manure from humans?  This is done in some places.

Comment: @badjohn if you eat an animal that dies anyways, you are also not hurting any animals, but vegans still don’t eat them. Conversely, if you eat plant based products that are made in a city that’s displaced and continues to displace tens of thousands of wildlife creatures, that would also be harming animals, but vegans don’t pay much attention to that, only “is it animal based”, or not.

Comment: Yes, I do not worry about the use of manure but I would not eat road kill.  Everyone sets their own rules.  This position is not entirely logical yet still common.  Partly, it is because I would find it hard to eat meat even in this case.  Also, because accepting this might lead to a slippery slope of allowing "accidents" to occur too often.

Comment: See also [Is aquaponic lettuce vegan?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2713/is-aquaponic-lettuce-vegan)

Comment: Can you please clarify if by "animal manure" you mean manure from "non-human animals" or are you also including humans that consent to have their manure composted and used as [humanure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compost#Human_excreta)?

Comment: Under what circumstance would a vegetable NOT be "vegan?"

Answer (score 1):

I help raise crops on a vegan farm.

On the farm, we have chickens.

The chicken poop is used as a manure to help the crops grow.

The chickens also eat the bugs that eat the crops.

The chickens themselves are not eaten except if other animals eat them (we use water sprinklers with special sensors to try to keep predators away).

I can't say if most vegan farms operate this way or if vegans in general find this practice acceptable.